# Communicate between pop up window and the parent window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, dom-events

I'm working on a PHP/MySQL project using Codeigniter framework.

The user fill a form with many data, and give me also FTP access to his web hosting, I want to POST FTP details to a popup after clicking Browse button, user will select a path (I'm using Codeigniter FTP Class), then I'll grab the path after the user click Save, or Close button.

Is there anyway to open a popup and post data to it, then the user will select something and I'll get what the user selected from the popup after closing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it will do what you want:

http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10321605

The gist is to set your action of the form to the page you want opened up in the popup, then return the popup function as the onSubmit handler of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do this, depending on where the input is supposed to end up, but I'd do it with Javascript in the popup window, which can refer to its parent page as "opener".

So set up an empty, hidden form variable on the main page -- let's call it "selectedvalue", in a form called "selectsaver" -- that will receive the value of whatever is selected in the popup window. In the popup window, when the element has been selected and the Save or Close button is clicked, the selected element is written into the selectedvalue field with

opener.selectsaver.selectedvalue.value = [selectedelementvalue]